# Re-apply a previously reverted commit in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I committed a change in revision 1. This caused the build to fail, so I reverted the changes in revision 2. In the meantime, other developers have committed a few revisions.

But now I want to re-apply the changes from revision 1 into a local Eclipse workspace to use as the starting-point of fixing the code. How can I do that?

In other words, I want to create a diff between revision 1 and head and apply those changes to my working copy.

**Imaginary SVN log:**

```
r1 Commit feature X  <--- I want this revision applied to my working-copy.
r2 Revert feature X 
...
r9 Bugfix
r10 Bugfix
r11 Bugfix
Head
```

Comment: This depends on how you "reverted the changes in revision 2". Did you use a reverse merge, an `svn copy`, a filesystem copy, or other?

Comment: I did a reverse merge. Are you about to tell me to reverse merge my reverse merge? Because I didn't think of that :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was going to tell you to do. Reverse-merge revision 2.

Comment: Yup, that worked, as expected. Feel free to answer the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reverse-merge revision #2 to undo undoing the change you made there.