# Rollback version in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have a Case: SVN has latest revision, say 100. But the code contains many bugs. Recommended revision is 80. Now, as SVN admin, what should we do that when developer takes svn update, he gets revision 80 by default, not 100.
Is it possible?
Any suggestions is appreciated! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16610562/1324345 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20049912/1324345

Comment: Thanks @alroc! 